# Multipleclicks on checkbox selected issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

What i did

> ```
>  1. create array of checkboxes with unique numeric ID 
>  2. on click of <td>(with unique numeric ID also ) i checked-unchecked the checkbox 
>  3. I used jQuery to check-uncheck logic.
> ```

**Problem :**
     When i click fresh on  it will change to checked.
     Then i again click on it and it unchecked.Then i continue this process and it gets stucks on checked.

**http://jsfiddle.net/5zQFe/**

Comment: Show the code, make a fiddle!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5zQFe/

Comment: First thing I see, is you are using the same id in both the td and the input. This most likely is an issue. Please fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, I just made sure the input was declared rather than the ID of the TD:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tdbox').click(function () {
        var tdID = $(this).attr('id');
        if ($(this).attr('id') == -1) {
            return false;
        }
        var inp = $(this).find("input[id=" + tdID + "]");

        if (inp.is(':checked')) {
            $(inp).prop("checked", false);
            $(this).css('background-color', "");
        } else {
            $(inp).prop("checked", true);
            $(this).css('background-color', "yellow");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Cool.. glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.prop("checked", false);
```

and

```
.prop("checked", 'checked');
```

in place of `.attr(...)`